# Simple A/B randomization script with PHP

Tags: php, random

I have two ad options in my theme, Adsense and "Custom". If the user enters code into the "Custom" field, it trumps whatever they have in the "Adsense" code field, so the theme places their custom ad atop the content area. If they have adsense enabled, and nothing in the custom ad spot, the theme places their adsense code there.

I'd like to add an option to allow the user to opt to have my theme automatically rotate ads between adsense and their custom ads. The custom ads may be Ebay, Amazon, ClickBank, etc.

How would you set up a PHP script that will randomly choose between two options?

Alternately, I'd like to be able to give the user the option to choose a percentage value so that the adsense ads are rotated based on their chosen percentage.

Just looking for some suggested approaches. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php

   $option[0] = 'html option 1';
   $option[1] = 'html option 2';

   echo $option[rand()%count($option)];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks simple enough. Could it be adopted to show option 1 by a stated percentage? Example, the user wants to insure option 1 is shown 75% of the time.

Comment: Yes add more same values with html you want to show more, you have a lil of redundancy but it's worth it

Comment: Can the value of each option be a function? $option[0] = doOption1();

Comment: You are asking a different question here :)

Comment: I'll post my 2nd question as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think mt_rand(); it's better than rand(); (source:http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)

2) 
   `$option[0] = 'html option 1';

   $option[1] = 'html option 1';

   $option[2] = 'html option 1';

   $option[3] = 'html option 2';`

echo $option[rand()%count($option)];

It's not a better solution, but it works :)

Comment: Your example in 2) uses rand() not mt_rand()