# Script to execute 1 of 2 functions randomly?

Tags: php, dynamic-function

Is it possible to modify the script below so that the value of each option is a function?

```
<?php

$option[0] = 'html option 1';
$option[1] = 'html option 2';

echo $option[rand()%count($option)];
?>
```

Obviously, this doesn't work:

```
function get_ads_rotation(){
    $option[0] = get_ad_option1();
    $option[1] = get_ad_option2();
   echo $option[rand()%count($option)];
```

}

(Props to yes123 for the [randomization script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215380/simple-a-b-randomization-script-with-php) above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct answer to the question: variables can store anonymous functions since PHP 5.3 only. It would be like this:

```
$option[1] = function($args) { /* do something here with $args */ };
```

However in preceding versions you could achieve something similar with [`call_user_func()`](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php), by storing function names in your options, and then passing the chosen option as the first argument. E.g.

```
$option[1] = 'functionOne';
// ...
call_user_func($option[1], /* other parameters if needed */);
```

However, it has a security hole, if the value is taken from user input.

Hence, more secure option would be to manually call the function depending on the chosen option with a [`switch`](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement:

```
switch ($option[rand()%count($option)]) {
    case 'html option 1' : functionOne(); break;
    case 'html option 2' : functionTwo(); break;
    case 'html option 3' : functionThree(); break;
    // ....
    default :  break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
$option[0] = 'get_ad_option1';
$option[1] = 'get_ad_option2';
echo call_user_func($option(...));
```